# Why do non-English characters show up as ??? in one table, but correctly in another?

Tags: sql-server, encoding, internationalization

I'm using SQL Server 2008 R2, and have two tables, both of which contain fields of type nvarchar(max). If I insert data into these tables using Query Analyser, and include non-English characters, one table stores them correctly, and the other stores them as question marks.

As far as I can see, the nvarchar(max) fields both tables look the same (apart from the name).

The database collation is Latin1_General_CI_AS if that helps.

I'm puzzled why one table works and the other doesn't. Anyone any ideas? Thanks

Comment: are you happening to insert into one table as N'my inserted value' and in the other 'my inserted value'?

Comment: No, I'm doing exactly the same on both. In truth, I actually do the data stuff via entity framework, but when this issue came up, I tried it out in query analyser to see where the problem lay and discovered this difference. If I can sort it out at the database level, then the EF code should work fine.

Comment: Are they really stored as question marks? That doesn't sound at all correct. BTW, query analyzer does not exist anymore. It went away after sql 2000.

Comment: They are question marks as far as I can see, both from the results in SSMS (yes I'm old fashioned and still think of it as query analyser), and from when I pull the data out. The Customers table shows the correct characters in both cases, and the other tables shows ??? in both.

Comment: Is your other table really contain column with `NVARCHAR` datatype in which you insert the data?? Please check again...

Comment: Yes, it really does use nvarchar! I've stared at it enough to be sure. I've tried changing it to varchar then back again, just to be extra sure, but it didn't help. It really, honestly and truly is nvarchar!